# How can I create CDF applications which adjust their screen dimensions based on the end-user's display configuration?

Tags: dynamic, cdf-format, deployment

I am trying to make a CDF application that takes the user's system information (screen information) and adjusts the size of the application to give a seamless experience over different screens with widely varying display properties.

Below is the code I tried. It should have worked, but it doesn't. I am very confused. The CDF is intended to be deployed in Player Pro/Mathematica.

```
CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], 
     CreateDocument[(Column[{Dynamic[CurrentValue["WindowSize"]], 
         Panel[GraphicsGrid[ConstantArray[1, {48, 78}],
                            ImageSize -> {800, 500},
                            Background -> RGBColor[.745, .886,.1],
                            Alignment -> {Left,Top},
                            ItemAspectRatio -> 1
                           ](*GraphicsGrid is Closed*), 
               Background -> Gray,
               Alignment ->{Center, Center}
               ](*Panel is Closed*)
        }])(*Column is Closed*), 
        WindowSize ->Dynamic[{Round[N[((780/96)*SystemInformation["Devices","ScreenInformation"][[1, 4, 2]])]], 
                                  Round[N[((780/96)*SystemInformation["Devices","ScreenInformation"][[1, 4, 2]])]]}]
    ](*CreateDocument is Closed*)
](*CdfDeploy is closed*)
```

Comment: How is the code not working? Do you get an error message? What behavior are you seeing when you run the code?

Comment: Is `WindowSize->Full` what you are looking for (full screen for whatever device is being used)?

Comment: When I have deployed it in to CDF, that CDF width and height in different system is same as it was in my system. But both have different screen resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be completely what you want, but it works:

```
CDFDeploy[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], DocumentNotebook[
         Column[{Dynamic[CurrentValue["WindowSize"]], 
             Panel[
         GraphicsGrid[ConstantArray[1, {48, 78}], ImageSize -> {800, 500}, 
                 Background -> RGBColor[0.745, 0.886, 0.1], 
          Alignment -> {Left, Top}, 
                 ItemAspectRatio -> 1], Background -> Gray, 
         Alignment -> {Center, Center}]}]], 
       WindowSize -> Flatten[Differences /@ 

        First["ScreenArea" /. 
          SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]]]
```

Comment: If I assign the below code to the WindowSize ,then it's not working.....why?                                                {Round[N[780/96*
    First["Resolution" /. 
      SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]]], 
 Round[N[480/96*
    First["Resolution" /. 
      SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]]]}

Comment: Because Resolution is not WindowSize.

Comment: @ Rolf Mertig : your code is working fine but the problem was whenever we open that cdf, the taskbar overlaps the horizontal scrollbar...why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is less flexible than the above solution, but it's fast and does most of the logic for you.... try doing this: `WindowSize->{Scaled[1/2],Scaled[1/2]}`